# Position Image in any Screen Resolution

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager

I have a problem with my program. Every time when I change my screen resolution, my image starts to move out of position. Any suggestions on how to make my image stay in the same location even though I change to any other resolution?

```
p2 = new JPanel();
p2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());      
ImageIcon img2 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Drum\\Invisible4.png");             
jbtn2 = new JLabel(img2);
p2.add(jbtn2);                      
add(jbtn2);
jbtn2.setSize(jbtn2.getPreferredSize());
jbtn2.setLocation(140, 380);
```

Comment: Don't try and position it manually, instead, use a layout manager...like `GridBagLayout` or `BorderLayout`.  The real question is, where do you actually want it

Comment: how to use the layout manager? Im creating a drum program. I need to put the drum cymbal and tom at a specific location so that it look like a drum set. the above code is just displaying one drum image.

Comment: Okay, does it need to scale?  So when the size of the window changes, do the images need to scale in proportion?

Comment: yes it need to scale in proportion too

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) for possible tips.

Comment: As does [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928)

Comment: I heard that I can use dynamic resolution. Any one has tips abt it?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to always try and work within boundaries of the framework where I can, it makes life generally easier in the long run.

Swing has begin designed to work with `LayoutManager`s, this means that the way that Swing updates it's components and communicates these changes is based on the use of the `LayoutManager`s (more or less).

The following example uses pieces from [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) to scale the images and a `PropertionalLayoutManager` which is designed to try and scale not only the size, but also the position of the components based on the size of the parent container.

The `PropertionalLayoutManager` demonstrated here will try and layout the components around the center of the parent container.  You can change this, but it looks weird - IMHO

[image][image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.LayoutManager2;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Drums {

    protected static BufferedImage SYMBOL;
    protected static BufferedImage DRUM;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Drums();
    }

    public Drums() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new PropertionalLayoutManager(400, 400));
            add(new Symbol(), new PropertionalConstraint(0f, 0));
            add(new Symbol(), new PropertionalConstraint(0.67f, 0));
            add(new Symbol(), new PropertionalConstraint(0f, 0.4675f));
            add(new Symbol(), new PropertionalConstraint(0.67f, 0.4675f));
            add(new Drum(), new PropertionalConstraint(0.205f, 0.1f));
            add(new Drum(), new PropertionalConstraint(0.5f, 0.1f));
            add(new Drum(), new PropertionalConstraint(0f, 0.33f));
            add(new Drum(), new PropertionalConstraint(0.705f, 0.33f));
        }
    }

    public class PropertionalConstraint {

        private float x;
        private float y;

        public PropertionalConstraint(float x, float y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public float getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public float getY() {
            return y;
        }
    }

    public class PropertionalLayoutManager implements LayoutManager2 {

        private Map<Component, PropertionalConstraint> constraints;
        private Dimension defaultSize;

        public PropertionalLayoutManager(int defaultWidth, int defaultHeight) {
            constraints = new WeakHashMap<>(25);
            defaultSize = new Dimension(defaultWidth, defaultHeight);
        }

        @Override
        public void addLayoutComponent(Component comp, Object constraint) {
            if (constraint instanceof PropertionalConstraint) {
                constraints.put(comp, ((PropertionalConstraint) constraint));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension maximumLayoutSize(Container target) {
            return preferredLayoutSize(target);
        }

        @Override
        public float getLayoutAlignmentX(Container target) {
            return 0.5f;
        }

        @Override
        public float getLayoutAlignmentY(Container target) {
            return 0.5f;
        }

        @Override
        public void invalidateLayout(Container target) {
        }

        @Override
        public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp) {
        }

        @Override
        public void removeLayoutComponent(Component comp) {
            constraints.remove(comp);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent) {

            return defaultSize;

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent) {
            return preferredLayoutSize(parent);
        }

        @Override
        public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {

            int width = parent.getWidth();
            int height = parent.getHeight();

            double dScaleWidth = getScaleFactor(defaultSize.width, width);
            double dScaleHeight = getScaleFactor(defaultSize.height, height);

            double scaleSize = Math.min(dScaleHeight, dScaleWidth);
            int minRange = Math.min(width, height);

            if (width > 0 && height > 0) {

                int maxY = 0;
                int maxX = 0;

                for (Component comp : parent.getComponents()) {
                    PropertionalConstraint p = constraints.get(comp);
                    if (p != null) {
                        Dimension prefSize = comp.getPreferredSize();

                        prefSize.width *= scaleSize;
                        prefSize.height *= scaleSize;

                        int x = Math.round(minRange * p.getX());
                        int y = Math.round(minRange * p.getY());

                        comp.setBounds(x, y, prefSize.width, prefSize.height);

                        maxX = Math.max(maxX, x + prefSize.width);
                        maxY = Math.max(maxY, y + prefSize.height);
                    } else {
                        comp.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    }
                }

                for (Component comp : parent.getComponents()) {
                    System.out.println("maxX = " + maxX);
                    System.out.println("maxY = " + maxY);
                    if (comp.getWidth() > 0 && comp.getHeight() > 0) {
                        int x = ((width - maxX) / 2) + comp.getX();
                        int y = ((height - maxY) / 2) + comp.getY();
                        comp.setLocation(x, y);
                    }                    
                }

            } else {

                for (Component comp : parent.getComponents()) {
                    comp.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
                }

            }

        }
    }

    public abstract class AbstractKitPiecePane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage scaled;

        public AbstractKitPiecePane() {
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        public abstract BufferedImage getKitImage();

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(getKitImage().getWidth(), getKitImage().getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        public void invalidate() {
            super.invalidate();
            if (getWidth() > 0 && getHeight() > 0) {
                scaled = getScaledInstanceToFit(getKitImage(), getSize());
            } else {
                scaled = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (scaled != null) {
                int x = (getWidth() - scaled.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - scaled.getHeight()) / 2;
                g.drawImage(scaled, x, y, this);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Drum extends AbstractKitPiecePane {

        @Override
        public BufferedImage getKitImage() {
            return DRUM;
        }
    }

    public class Symbol extends AbstractKitPiecePane {

        @Override
        public BufferedImage getKitImage() {
            return SYMBOL;
        }
    }

    protected static BufferedImage getScaledInstance(BufferedImage img, double dScaleFactor) {

        BufferedImage imgScale = img;

        int iImageWidth = (int) Math.round(img.getWidth() * dScaleFactor);
        int iImageHeight = (int) Math.round(img.getHeight() * dScaleFactor);

        if (dScaleFactor <= 1.0d) {

            imgScale = getScaledDownInstance(img, iImageWidth, iImageHeight, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);

        } else {

            imgScale = getScaledUpInstance(img, iImageWidth, iImageHeight, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);

        }

        return imgScale;

    }

    protected static BufferedImage getScaledDownInstance(BufferedImage img,
            int targetWidth,
            int targetHeight,
            Object hint) {

//        System.out.println("Scale down...");
        int type = (img.getTransparency() == Transparency.OPAQUE)
                ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB : BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;

        BufferedImage ret = (BufferedImage) img;

        if (targetHeight > 0 || targetWidth > 0) {
            int w, h;
            w = img.getWidth();
            h = img.getHeight();

            do {

                if (w > targetWidth) {
                    w /= 2;
                    if (w < targetWidth) {
                        w = targetWidth;
                    }
                }

                if (h > targetHeight) {
                    h /= 2;
                    if (h < targetHeight) {
                        h = targetHeight;
                    }
                }

                BufferedImage tmp = new BufferedImage(Math.max(w, 1), Math.max(h, 1), type);
                Graphics2D g2 = tmp.createGraphics();
                g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, hint);
                g2.drawImage(ret, 0, 0, w, h, null);
                g2.dispose();

                ret = tmp;

            } while (w != targetWidth || h != targetHeight);
        } else {
            ret = new BufferedImage(1, 1, type);
        }

        return ret;
    }

    protected static BufferedImage getScaledUpInstance(BufferedImage img,
            int targetWidth,
            int targetHeight,
            Object hint) {

        int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;

        BufferedImage ret = (BufferedImage) img;
        int w, h;
        w = img.getWidth();
        h = img.getHeight();

        do {
            if (w < targetWidth) {
                w *= 2;
                if (w > targetWidth) {
                    w = targetWidth;
                }
            }

            if (h < targetHeight) {
                h *= 2;
                if (h > targetHeight) {
                    h = targetHeight;
                }
            }

            BufferedImage tmp = new BufferedImage(w, h, type);
            Graphics2D g2 = tmp.createGraphics();
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, hint);
            g2.drawImage(ret, 0, 0, w, h, null);
            g2.dispose();

            ret = tmp;
            tmp = null;
        } while (w != targetWidth || h != targetHeight);

        return ret;
    }

    public static BufferedImage getScaledInstanceToFit(BufferedImage img, Dimension size) {
        double scaleFactor = getScaleFactorToFit(img, size);
        return getScaledInstance(img, scaleFactor);
    }

    public static double getScaleFactorToFit(BufferedImage img, Dimension size) {
        double dScale = 1;

        if (img != null) {
            int imageWidth = img.getWidth();
            int imageHeight = img.getHeight();
            dScale = getScaleFactorToFit(new Dimension(imageWidth, imageHeight), size);
        }

        return dScale;
    }

    public static double getScaleFactorToFit(Dimension original, Dimension toFit) {
        double dScale = 1d;

        if (original != null && toFit != null) {
            double dScaleWidth = getScaleFactor(original.width, toFit.width);
            double dScaleHeight = getScaleFactor(original.height, toFit.height);
            dScale = Math.min(dScaleHeight, dScaleWidth);
        }

        return dScale;
    }

    public static double getScaleFactor(int iMasterSize, int iTargetSize) {
        double dScale = 1;
        if (iMasterSize > iTargetSize) {
            dScale = (double) iTargetSize / (double) iMasterSize;
        } else {
            dScale = (double) iTargetSize / (double) iMasterSize;
        }

        return dScale;
    }

    static {

        try {
            SYMBOL = ImageIO.read(new File("Symbol.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            DRUM = ImageIO.read(new File("Drum.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

And the images used within the program, for your enjoyment.  They live in the same directory the program is run from

[image][image]

Comment: I try run the program but it display me this error:

javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
 at test.<clinit>(test.java:405)
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
 at test.<clinit>(test.java:410)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Of course, you need to supply you own images of the symbols and drums :P

Comment: @mKorbel Yeah, couldn't find any :P

Comment: Thanks for the working code. Any idea where i can insert the mouseListener to the following image

Comment: The best way would be to attach it to the component itself.  If you wanted to use a single listener on the top level panel, you could use `getComponentAt(Point)` in your mouse listener to find the component that was clicked

Answer (score 0):

create a percentage/ratio of the "normal" screen size to what it currently is and multiply that by the pos. Example if the screen size you are working with was 400x600

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double width = screenSize.getWidth();
double height = screenSize.getHeight();
double widthRat = width/600
double heightRat = height/400
```

then

```
jbtn2.setLocation(140*widthRat, 380*heightRat);
```

that way say the screen size was doubled to 1200x800 widthRat would = 2 and double the position. This is kind of a sloppy example but gives the idea

Comment: IMHO, you be better of designing a proportional layout manager that was capable of defining a size and position of the components based on there preferred sizes and the size of the actual container.  This way you don't need to add a multitude of listeners to keep it all updated as you'd be working within the Swing framework

Comment: True i wasn't really thinking about increasing size on demand.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use Absolute layout. And here are the codes which should work for you.

```
Toolkit toolkit=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
JPanel1.setSize(toolkit.getScreenSize().width, toolkit.getScreenSize().height);
int w=toolkit.getScreenSize().width;
int h=toolkit.getScreenSize().height;
JPanel1.setBounds(0, 0, w, h);
```

This code will fetch the current resolution of your computer...