# How to use dynamic method resolution for different screen resolution

Tags: java, eclipse, screen-resolution

I need to make a program that hold my image in a specific location without it moving around when I change my screen resolution.

```
public KinderDrum(){
     setSize(1000,500);
     setTitle("Drum");
     setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
     setUndecorated(true); 
     setLayout(new BorderLayout());



     JButton button = new JButton("Exit");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
          }
        });
        getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);


     p1 = new JPanel();
     p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
     ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Drum\\Word.png");
     jlblImage = new JLabel(img);
     p1.add(jlblImage);

             add(jlblImage);
     jlblImage.setSize(jlblImage.getPreferredSize());
     jlblImage.setLocation(300, 550);
```

Comment: And what was wrong with the answers from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847816/position-image-in-any-screen-resolution)?

Comment: my teacher ask to used dynamic method instead :(

Comment: Is the location you mentioned relative to screen or relative to JFrame?