# Error while adding mouseListener to BufferedImage

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, bufferedimage, mouse-listeners

I want to produced a sound when I clicked on one of my buffereImage. But it display me this error: The method addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){}) is undefined for the type BufferedImage

here are the code:

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    public TestPane() {
        setLayout(new PropertionalLayoutManager(400, 400));
        add(new Symbol(), new PropertionalConstraint(0f, 0));
        add(new Symbol(), new PropertionalConstraint(0.67f, 0));
        //add(new Symbol(), new PropertionalConstraint(0f, 0.4675f));
        //add(new Symbol(), new PropertionalConstraint(0.67f, 0.4675f));
        add(new Drum(), new PropertionalConstraint(0.205f, 0.1f));
        add(new Drum(), new PropertionalConstraint(0.5f, 0.1f));
        add(new Drum(), new PropertionalConstraint(0f, 0.33f));
        add(new Drum(), new PropertionalConstraint(0.705f, 0.33f));


     DRUM.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
     {
          public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) 
          {
            Sound1.Sound5.play();
          }
        }); 


    }static {

    try {
        SYMBOL = ImageIO.read(new File("HiCrash.png"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        DRUM = ImageIO.read(new File("HiTom.png"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: `MouseListener` can only be added to a component that can be made visible on the screen.  By default a `BufferedImage` can not be displayed on screen, without first being wrapped by some component (like `JLabel` or painted onto the surface of a `JPanel`, for example).

Comment: So how can I insert the bufferedImage to a JPanel?

Comment: Take a look at my answer ;)

Comment: I have to ask: What's a propertion?

Comment: @roippi It's a custom layout manager that I wrote for jat some time ago which attempts to resize the components it has based on an initial size and there `PropertionalConstraint` (and preferred size).  If you're really curious, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847816/position-image-in-any-screen-resolution

Answer (score 1):

`MouseListener` can only be added to a component that can be made visible on the screen.  By default a `BufferedImage` can not be displayed on screen, without first being wrapped by some component (like `JLabel` or painted onto the surface of a `JPanel`, for example).

Actually, you can't add a mouse listener to anything that doesn't provide support for it...

Instead, add the `MouseListener` to the `Drum` or `Symbol` class

You might want to take a read through [How to write a mouse listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer. I still dont understand much. You have help me alot

Comment: The more I seem to learn, the less I seem to know :P.  Best teacher is experience, keep trying and see where it takes you